# Changes to User Defined Functions in Office 365 Subscription based

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

I've seen issues a couple of times when using User Defined Functions with Excel from subscription-based Office 365.

When a workbook is opened with these formulas, they are automatically updated. Excel puts an @ sign before the equals sign in the formula.

This breaks the formula. A temporary workaround is to use search and replace to remove the @ signs.

I've searched the Microsoft site and couldn't find anything. I've also done multiple web searches, but I haven't found anything there either.

Has anyone seen this issue, and if so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34